# Wordpress posts in the loop not stacking side by side

Tags: loop, css

I was following a wp theme developement tutorial but somehow the posts from main loop and projects are not showing side by side ..although all other css works fine
here is my code

front-page.php

```
<?php get_header();?>

    <div id="banner">
        <h1>&lt;GTCoding/&gt;</h1>
        <h3>Learn coding from scratch</h3>
    </div>

    <main>
        <a href="<?php echo site_url('/blog');?>">
            <h2 class="section-heading">All Blogs</h2>
        </a>

      <?php
        $args =  array(
         'post_type' => 'post',
         'posts_per_page' => 2
        );
        $blogposts = new WP_Query($args);

        while($blogposts->have_posts()){
            $blogposts->the_post();

      ?>
        <section>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>" alt="Card Image">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="card-description">
                    <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    </a>
                    <p>
                       <?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(),30); ?>
                    </p>
                    <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn-readmore">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
          <?php } 
            wp_reset_query(); 
          ?>

        </section>

        <a href="<?php echo site_url('/projects');?>">
            <h2 class="section-heading">All Projects</h2>
        </a>

        <?php
        $args =  array(
         'post_type' => 'project',
         'posts_per_page' => 2
        );
        $projects = new WP_Query($args);

        while($projects->have_posts()){
            $projects->the_post();

      ?>
        <section>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>" alt="Card Image">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="card-description">
                    <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    </a>
                    <p>
                       <?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(),30); ?>
                    </p>
                    <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn-readmore">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
          <?php } 
            wp_reset_query(); 
          ?>

        </section>

        <h2 class="section-heading">Source Code</h2>

        <section id="section-source">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum neque qui delectus ad dolor blanditiis perferendis praesentium
                consectetur aut sed provident obcaecati aspernatur perspiciatis, dolores nobis pariatur ipsum vel corrupti!
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="btn-readmore">GitHub Profile</a>
        </section>

      <?php get_footer();?>
```

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>GTCoding</title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="slideout-menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('');?>">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('/blog');?>">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('/projects');?>">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('/about');?>">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search Here">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <nav>
        <div id="logo-img">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/img/logo.png" alt="GTCoding Logo">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="menu-icon">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="active" href="<?php echo site_url('');?>">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('/blog');?>">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('/projects');?>">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('/about');?>">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div id="search-icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="searchbox">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search Here">
    </div>
```

footer.php

```
  <footer>
            <div id="left-footer">
                <h3>Quick Links</h3>
                <p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="about.html">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="blogslist.html">Blogs</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="blogslist.html">Projects</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </p>
            </div>

            <div id="right-footer">
                <h3>Follow us on</h3>
                <div id="social-media-footer">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <p>This website is developed by GTCoding</p>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </main>

 <?php wp_footer();?>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

it should show like this

[image]

here is my index.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Roboto+Condensed|Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>GTCoding</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="slideout-menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="blogslist.html">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="blogslist.html">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search Here">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <nav>
        <div id="logo-img">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="GTCoding Logo">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="menu-icon">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="blogslist.html">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="blogslist.html">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div id="search-icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="searchbox">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search Here">
    </div>

    <div id="banner">
        <h1>&lt;GTCoding/&gt;</h1>
        <h3>Learn coding from scratch</h3>
    </div>

    <main>
        <a href="blogslist.html">
            <h2 class="section-heading">All Blogs</h2>
        </a>

        <section>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <a href="blogpost.html">
                        <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Card Image">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="card-description">
                    <a href="blogpost.html">
                        <h3>The Blog Title Here</h3>
                    </a>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, ullam facilis consequuntur eligendi sit accusamus tempora
                        cum distinctio pariatur ipsa quod, odit dolorum non vero recusandae? Corporis voluptatem optio nulla.
                    </p>
                    <a href="blogpost.html" class="btn-readmore">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <a href="blogpost.html">
                        <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="Card Image">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="card-description">
                    <a href="blogpost.html">
                        <h3>The Blog Title Here</h3>
                    </a>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, ullam facilis consequuntur eligendi sit accusamus tempora
                        cum distinctio pariatur ipsa quod, odit dolorum non vero recusandae? Corporis voluptatem optio nulla.
                    </p>
                    <a href="blogpost.html" class="btn-readmore">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <a href="blogslist.html">
            <h2 class="section-heading">All Projects</h2>
        </a>

        <section>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <a href="blogpost.html">
                        <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="Card Image">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="card-description">
                    <a href="blogpost.html">
                        <h3>The Project Title Here</h3>
                    </a>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, ullam facilis consequuntur eligendi sit accusamus tempora
                        cum distinctio pariatur ipsa quod, odit dolorum non vero recusandae? Corporis voluptatem optio nulla.
                    </p>
                    <a href="blogpost.html" class="btn-readmore">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <a href="blogpost.html">
                        <img src="img/4.jpg" alt="Card Image">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="card-description">
                    <a href="blogpost.html">
                        <h3>The Project Title Here</h3>
                    </a>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, ullam facilis consequuntur eligendi sit accusamus tempora
                        cum distinctio pariatur ipsa quod, odit dolorum non vero recusandae? Corporis voluptatem optio nulla.
                    </p>
                    <a href="blogpost.html" class="btn-readmore">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <h2 class="section-heading">Source Code</h2>

        <section id="section-source">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum neque qui delectus ad dolor blanditiis perferendis praesentium
                consectetur aut sed provident obcaecati aspernatur perspiciatis, dolores nobis pariatur ipsum vel corrupti!
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="btn-readmore">GitHub Profile</a>
        </section>

        <footer>
            <div id="left-footer">
                <h3>Quick Links</h3>
                <p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="about.html">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="blogslist.html">Blogs</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="blogslist.html">Projects</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </p>
            </div>

            <div id="right-footer">
                <h3>Follow us on</h3>
                <div id="social-media-footer">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <p>This website is developed by GTCoding</p>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </main>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found your issue and it is "section" tag. You have written "section" tag inside the while loop. so it must need put "section" tag outside of the while loop and check it again. Hope it's works fine.

Comment: thanks..that did it